# C# close pdf opened with PdfiumViewer

Tags: c#, pdf

I 'm using to PdfiumViewer convert pdf to image

```
var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(pdfoutputFilePath + TafCode + ".pdf");  
var image = document.Render(0, 842, 595, true);  
image.Save(imageoutputFilePath + TafCode + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

When I do I remove pdf

An error opening the PDF!

How close pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose saving to image code into using to make sure 'Dispose' is called and resources are unlocked.

```
using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(pdfoutputFilePath + TafCode + ".pdf"))
{
    var image = document.Render(0, 842, 595, true);  
    image.Save(imageoutputFilePath + TafCode + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

You can tell that by looking at the code of PdfDocument class which defines 'Dispose' method to free the file accordingly.

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.</summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">Whether this method is called from Dispose.</param>
    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed && disposing)
        {
            if (_file != null)
            {
                _file.Dispose();
                _file = null;
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

to close the opened document

```
    if (document.Document != null)
    {
      document.Document.Dispose();
    }
```